# How can I take database backup with password in SQL Server 2012 or higher version?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, database-backups, sql-server-2016

I can create database backup with password in SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2. But In SQL Server 2012 and 2016, I failed to create password protected database backups.

If backup has no password, then my database may be restored by anybody and then data confidentiality as well as database schema may be disclosed. Please help me if anybody knows how to take password protected backup in SQL Server 2012 and 2016.

I am using this script to create backup with password in SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2008 as well as SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
Backup database DATABASENAME 
To Disk = 'd:\databasebackup.bak' 
with Password='dbpassword', INIT
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-an-encrypted-backup

Answer (score 0):

Basically you now have to use a certificate, once you have a certificate configured

```
BACKUP DATABASE DATABASENAME To Disk = 'd:\databasebackup.bak' 
WITH  
  ENCRYPTION   
   (  
   ALGORITHM = AES_256,  
   SERVER CERTIFICATE = MyCert  
   ),
```

Full details here as I pointed out in the comment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-an-encrypted-backup